# Bounding super exponential functions with factorial functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, factorial

I want to show that there exists polynomials $q(n)$, $p(n)$ with integer coefficeints such that
$$
(q(n)!)^{p(n)} > 2^{2^n}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.  Intuitively this inequality seems to make since, and rought numerical simulations I have done suggest that it holds, but I cannot figure out a proof.  Does anyone have any ideas as to whether this is true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take logarithms of both sides, we then want to have $p(n) \cdot \log_2 q(n)! > 2^n$.

We can use very rough estimation, $k! < k^k$, to get that left side is less than $p(n) \cdot q(n)\cdot \log_2 q(n)$.
Which is less than $p(n) \cdot q(n) \cdot cn$ - polynomial. Given that right side is exponential in $n$, for all large enough $n$ the inequality is false.